# Предлагает поставить ";", но где и зачем?

Tags: android, kotlin, gradle

Текст ошибки: Unexpected tokens (use ';' to separate expressions on the same line)

Подчеркивает красным: "https://jitpack.io"

```
dependencyResolutionManagement {
    repositoriesMode.set(RepositoriesMode.FAIL_ON_PROJECT_REPOS)
    repositories {
        google()
        mavenCentral()
        maven { url "https://jitpack.io" }

    }
}
```

Comment: [пожалуйста, не добавляйте код/данные/текст ошибок картинками.](//ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/12119)

Answer (score 4):

Если у вас `.kts` формат у build.gradle, то может помочь это:

```
maven { url = uri("https://jitpack.io") }
```

вот [пример](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63332275/unexpected-tokens-use-to-separate-expressions-on-the-same-line-in-build-gr)

Comment: Спасибо.
То что нужно!

Comment: если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как принятый нажав на галочку слева от него